# How to restart git repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I've fetched a repo from one of my old projects and I've edited the files so I can use this as a 'skeleton' for new projects. Say I'm here:

/skeleton/framework

I already have the repo there, edited. How would I go about restarting this repo with those files in that directory? What *should* I have done?

All I did was pull the repo and edit and push to a different named repo (skeleton.git). Trouble is, this repo obviously contains all the history of the repo I pulled from.

Comment: If you want to restart a git repo, nuke the `.git` directory and do `git init` add your files/directories and commit.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you just want to keep your current working tree, and lose all git history etc. you can do

```
rm -rf .git
git init .
```

Comment: then add `git commit -am .` and `git push`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove .git and all trace. then copy the app to another location in the hard drive and start all over again (git init . and so on...)