# Clean Android project on github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, project

I was developing my app on PC and backuping my work on GitHub. I bought a new laptop so I wanted to use GitHub and work simultaneously on both devices. I tried to import project to Android Studio but project structure was blank/empty. Problem was that I didn't had some files on github, had them only local on PC. (in this stage I tried it https://github.com/ankhthief/FirstAidLog/commit/a4844d46748af15f90ec12c23672cb92dcfd229d). I used TeamViewer to connect to my PC and synch important gradle files to github as well. I managed to sucesfully import my project to notebook but then i got lost and made several commits with another files and I ended with messed GitHub with several files I guess I don't need on both computer. Can anyone help me to clean my project and set it up so it will work fine on both devices? Link to project: https://github.com/ankhthief/FirstAidLog.

I'm quite new to Git as well as Android, so if I'm going to need to use commands for Git I will prefer step-by-step tutorial for begginers :)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can checkout the project, build and run it. 
The `FloatingActionButton` has a plus sign, which was your intention with [the commit](https://github.com/ankhthief/FirstAidLog/commit/a4844d46748af15f90ec12c23672cb92dcfd229d) you mentioned.

If the project doesn't build on your PC(s), I assume you screwed up your local copy of the project. I suggest the following:

- make a backup of your project's folder
- check out a fresh copy of your project from Github 
  `git clone git@github.com:ankhthief/FirstAidLog.git`
- open your fresh copy in Android Studio

If for some reason you feel you need to completely start over with your repository (local and remote) then

- check out the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244644/how-to-restart-a-git-repository) to start a new local repository, do this on the PC where you feel 'things are right'
- add only the files you want to have in your repository
- overwrite your remote repository (Github) with [git push --force](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)
- re-checkout the project on the other PC (see above)

Comment: I can run/build app on laptop as well on PC, but I messed the commit so I start synchronizing files like .gradle/3.3/... and I make mess on both devices. But I guess second part of your answer should help me. Thanks.