# How do I restart a git project, and keep its history?

Tags: git

*Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018747/how-do-i-restart-a-git-github-project), but here I do care about forkers and history.*

I restarted a project from scratch, and now I want to append it as a commit to an existing git repository. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just wondering - if you can delete all current contents using `git rm` and push it as commit - wouldn't that give you a clean repository with history?

Comment: Instead of deleting everything using `git rm`, you can also simply delete `.git/index`, which has the same effect, but is easier to achieve when all the old content in the working directory is already gone.

Comment: Something like `git push new-repo old-repo/master:old-master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `.git` of the old repo, and in the new git repo:

```
cd /path/to/new/git/repo
git add --work-tree=/path/to/old/git/repo add -A .
```